# problem add library recyclerView in android studio

Tags: android

i have problem to add library at android studio . i need help to fix this problem . Thankful

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Error building project:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: recyclerview 
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: [link](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/3906315636047599298_m.PNG)

Comment: Warning:<i><b>project ':app': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugImplementationDependenciesMetadata'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find recyclerview.jar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.0.0/recyclerview-1.0.0.jar</i>

Comment: welcome to  stackoverflow, please read [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `recycleview` lib in gradle for `androidx` . just add this below lib. this package contains  `recycleView` inside it.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change recyclerview library with :

```
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using all the dependencies from AndroidX. That means your project is in AndroidX. But the `RecyclerView` dependency you're trying to add is from support library that won't work with AndroidX.

Use this AndroidX dependecy instead:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```